# convert audio to wav/mp3 using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mp3, media, encode, wav

I'm trying to convert an audio file directly recorded from the browser in a friendly format, such as wav or mp3, using only pure JavaScript, I've tried several things but nothing worked so far.

The only thing I managed to do is to record audio from the browser. 
Here's my code :

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start();
    const audioChunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
      audioChunks.push(event.data);
    });
    mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks);
      const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
      const audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
    }, 3000);
  });
```

Comment: Looks like you don't really want to convert an audio file... you want to record one.  What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Well I managed to record an audio but I need to convert it into wav or mp3 to send it to my database, but I have no idea how...

Comment: You could record to WAV in the first place by specifying the codec when you instantiate the MediaRecorder.  I don't recall if that's well supported yet or not.  MP3 definitely isn't well supported.  Why not just keep the codec it's already recorded in?  (It's probably going to be Opus in WebM, which is far superior to MP3.)  Or if you must transcode, why not do it on the server?